# gulp stripe off lib folder, got error of cannot find module

Tags: javascript, node.js, gulp

```
import myPersonalModule from './lib/myPersonalModule'
```

this work before I run gulp but after I run gulp command I enter my page I see error of

Error: Cannot find module "./lib/myPersonalModule"

Comment: Probably a gulp task is moving the `lib`s into another folder.

Comment: @Tushar maybe, how to resolve it? change lib to another name?

Comment: Can you add Gulpfile.js here.